# Laravel relationship returning 1 for input value

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship

I have a text input:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name',  $car->basicCustomer->first_name or NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled']) }}
```

Which should return a first name, but instead the input has a value of 1.

The relationship when die and dumped returns:

```
object(Customer)#805 (20) {
  ["connection":protected] "main_site"
  ["fillable":protected] array(8) {
    [0] "title"
    [1] "first_name"
    [2] "last_name"
    [3] "email"
    [4] "telephone_number"
    [5] "address"
    [6] "post_code"
    [7] "company_name"
  }
  ["table":protected] NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected] "id"
  ["perPage":protected] 15
  ["incrementing"] true
  ["timestamps"] true
  ["attributes":protected] array(3) {
    ["first_name"] "John"
    ["last_name"] "Doe"
    ["id"] "19854"
  }
  ["original":protected] array(3) {
    ["first_name"] "John"
    ["last_name"] "Doe"
    ["id"] "19854"
  etc...
```

The value in the input is always 1, even if calling the last_name etc.

Any ideas whats happening?

EDIT: Fixed the error by luck, needed to use and if to check if the relationship wasn't null in another view:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', (!$car->basicCustomer ? NULL : $car->basicCustomer->first_name), ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled']) }}
```

This now outputs the name, can anyone explain why the:

or NULL

wasn't working?

Comment: The or NULL was interpreted as a conditional expression. And it return true (1) or false (0). "Any string" OR NULL was returning true (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or NULL` is interpreted as a conditional expression. And it return true (1) or false (0).

```
'test' or null :    
boolean true

'' or null :    
boolean false

true or null :
boolean true

false or null :    
boolean false
```

In your case you can use the `?:` operator.

```
$string ?: null
```

Which is a shorter version for

```
$string ? $string : null
```